# Android Play video from streaming

Tags: android

I'm streaming from a website with the following code :

```
        private VideoView mVideoView;

        mVideoView.setVideoURI(vid);                
        mVideoView.setMediaController(new MediaController(this));
        mVideoView.requestFocus();              
        mVideoView.postInvalidateDelayed(100);        
        mVideoView.start();
```

and everything is fine but it takes time to start the load and i see in the log cat the following line :

**D/MediaPlayer(10843): Couldn't open file on client side, trying server side**

is there a way to make it load from the web immediately ? 
Thanks

Comment: is it possible the video url is from youtube ? have you also tried calling "prepare" (i think this way you could at least tell the user to wait till it's prepared to play) .

Answer (score 0):

Is it a file on SD card or external URL? please provide apropriate permission to read SD card or to connect onilne in the manifest file.

[Check out this](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html)

Comment: not a problem did it already, My problem is that i want to first try looking up online with out first searching in the internal storage.

Comment: I don't think you can play instanly. It streams teh video and then plays.

Comment: I know, but it keeps giving me the log that :
D/MediaPlayer(10843): Couldn't open file on client side, trying server side     - and it seems that this is the time consuming thing, or maybe i'm wrong